# returning unsigned character [] from the jni

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to return the unsigned character [] from my jni method . I  have following code in the Jni function :

```
unsigned char abc[16]
 abc[i] = 'b';
```

I have used jstring and jcharArray  for returning the abc to the java code. But while using the jstring i am not able to compile the program correctly. anb while using the chararray i am getting some weird characters . Please suggest some solution how to deal with this problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JNI unsigned char to byte array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4610774/jni-unsigned-char-to-byte-array)

Comment: @DavidWasser:but in that question i am just confused with the return type of the data variable void *data = env->GetPrimitiveArrayCritical((jarray)bArray, &isCopy);

Comment: Forget the referenced question, it may not be helpful. Does your `unsigned char` array actually contain characters? are they 7-bit only?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Java datatype that corresponds to C `unsigned char` is, in fact, `byte`. You need to declare your method as returning `byte[]` on the Java side, and act accordingly on the C side.

Whether this is the right thing to do is another question. In C, "a string of text" and "an array of bytes" are pretty much synonyms (modulo null termination); in Java, not so. Is this a string of readable (ASCII) text? If it is, it **is** more natural to return it as a `jstring`; to convert from a C `[unsigned] char *` to a `jstring`, use `JNIEnv::NewStringUTF()`. But then there's another caveat: if your string is in a codepage other than UTF-8 and has non-ASCII characters (code >= 0x80), this won't work; then you're better off passing the string out as a byte array and converting it via the right codepage on the Java side.

Answer (score 0):

After I've done all the work in C++ I'm copying the data from a regular native byte array (actually it is `unsigned char *dataB`) to a new JNI object `jbyteArray` (same thing but for JNI) which can be returned back to Java code:

```
...
//Prepare jbyteArray to return to Java
jbyteArray resultReturn = env->NewByteArray(dataLength);
//copy data:
env->SetByteArrayRegion(resultReturn, 0, dataLength, reinterpret_cast<const jbyte *>(dataB));

    return resultReturn;
}
```

where dataB is an array of bytes `unsigned char *dataB` which has all the data I worked with.